# how can one make a JComboBox dropdown when it is given focus?

Tags: java, swing, drop-down-menu, jcombobox

I find that a useful way to draw attention to a jcombobox when one wants the user to select from it is to make it drop down at the point it gains focus usually when the previous item has been completed by the user.
How can this been done in Java?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could do:

```
comboBox.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {

   @Override
   public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
      comboBox.showPopup();
   }
});
```

Comment: +1 notice FocusListener and with ItemListener together can causing endless loop, sure depends of code inside both listners

Comment: But how can a jcombobox open on mouseover instead of opening on mouse click?

Answer (score 6):

You want [`JComboBox#setPopupVisible`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setPopupVisible%28boolean%29)

Add in a `FocusListener` to monitor for focus gained and you should be right.

Depending on if the combo box is editable or not, you may need to add a focus listener to the editor as well

Answer (score 1):

rightclick on the combo box. go to events ---> mouse ----> mouseentered.
it will take you to : 
private void jComboBox1MouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {}
inside the curly braces, type: jComboBox1.showPopup();

it should look like:

```
private void jComboBox1MouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        jComboBox1.showPopup();
    }
```